# getopt_long setting optstring[0] to '+'

Tags: c, getopt

According to the man page for getopt and getopt_long, the GNU version reorders argv so that anything resembling a flag will be first, then it will return -1 when it reaches the first string that is not a flag.  It also says that when optstring[0] is set to '+', it will not reorder the arguments.  How do I set optstring[0] to '+'?  I tried simply tossing in a optstring[0] = '+'; assignment statement, and I rightfully got that optstring is undeclared.

Comment: it means the string you are passing into getopt (the argument is called optstring)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`optstring` is the third argument to [`getopt_long`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/getopt_long), declared as:

```
int getopt_long(int argc, char * const argv[],
           const char *optstring,
           const struct option *longopts, int *longindex);
```

Call the function with an `optstring` that begins with `+`:

```
getopt_long(argc, argv, "+abc:d:f:", long_options, &option_index);
```

Comment: Thank you.  I have no idea how that eluded me.